# Different languages for sphinx-proof

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm currently working with the sphinx-proof extension and was wondering if one somehow could change the spelling of the different titles into other languages? I did try playing around in the directive.py but it keeps changing the format/layout of the block when trying to label "Proof" as "Preuve".

Btw, I'm quite new to this universe of coding, so an elaborated answer is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like i18n support is missing in sphinx-proof: https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-proof/issues/70

Comment: @mzjn, yeah. I stumbled upon sphinxcontrib-proof but for Furo the html output looks silly imo, I guess I'll have to wait.